# lodash chunk to turn mapped into two

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a set of data and want to construct a table for it. 
This is the data from API

```
[
  {
    date: "1/11",
    data: [
      {
        camera: "camera 1",
        count: 10
      },
      {
        camera: "camera 2",
        count: 20
      },
      {
        camera: "camera 3",
        count: 30
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my jxs

```
<table className="tg">
      <tr>
        <th />
        {Object.values(data[0].data).map((o, i) => <th>{o.camera}</th>)}
      </tr>
      {data.map((o, i) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{o.date}</td>
            {o.data.map(o2 => <td>{o2.count}</td>)}
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
```

Demo can be seen here https://codesandbox.io/s/pm8qm68onq

but the problem is there will be more cameras! It won't fit 20 cameras, so how can I split another 10 cameras if the data set has 18 cameras? I want to create another table if the cameras is more than 10, so first 10 cameras will be in the first table and second table would contains 8 cameras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go through each date and build a new array of the applicable tables.

```
let newData = [];

for (const dateObj of data) {
  let chunkedData = [];
  while (dateObj.data.length > 0)
    chunkedData.push(dateObj.data.splice(0, 2));
  for (const [index, chunk] of chunkedData.entries()) {
    newData[index] = newData[index] || [];
    newData[index].push({
      date: dateObj.date,
      data: chunk
    })
  }
}
```

You can then loop over tables in your JSX.

```
<div>
  {newData.map((table, i) => {
    return (
      <table className="tg">
        <tr>
          <th />
          {Object.values(table[0].data).map((o, i) => <th>{o.camera}</th>)}
        </tr>
        {table.map((o, i) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{o.date}</td>
                {o.data.map(o2 => <td>{o2.count}</td>)}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      );
    })
  }
</div>
```

I have updated your demo to do this using a max of 2 cameras per table... https://codesandbox.io/s/jn4w32v759

Comment: very confusing in this line   `for (const [index, chunk] of chunkedData.entries()) {`

Comment: It is just way of accessing the key, value pairs within the for of loop. As we are looping over an array the index is the key. It could be substituted for a different type of loop if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to slice your data into chunks before `render`

```
sliceIntoChunks = (data, chunkSize) => {
    let chunks = [];
    for (let i=0; i<data.length; i+=chunkSize) {
        chunks.push(data.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

Then in render for each chunk create a separate table:

```
chunks.map(chunk => (
    <table>
        // and map through chunk to fill current table
        chank.map(camera => (...))
    </table>
))
```

---

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/csr6zsbo/

Comment: tested this, this won't work. it will have repeated camera on the tables.